# How can I update High Order Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I created array of routing in ReactJS

```
const routes = [
  { id: 0, path: '/', view: Home, parent: 0 },
  { id: 1, path: '/a', view: Home2, parent: 0 },
  { id: 2, path: '/b', view: Home3, parent: 1 }
]
```

Created HOC withAuth which should back to parent routing when user isn't logged. When i going to route (as not logged) - its ok and withAuth back me to parent route, but when i am on route and logout page isn't refresh and I am stay on route for logged users.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AuthHelper from "./AuthHelper";

export default function withAuth(AuthComponent) {
  const Auth = new AuthHelper();

  class AuthWrapped extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        confirm: null,
        loaded: false
      };
    }

    checkLogged = () => {
      if (!Auth.loggedIn()) {

        const parent = this.props.parent;
        const obj = this.props.routes
        .filter(v => v.id === parent);
        this.props.history.replace(obj[0].path);

      } else {
        try {
          const confirm = Auth.getConfirm();
          this.setState({
            confirm: confirm,
            loaded: true
          });
        } catch (err) {
          Auth.logout();
          this.props.history.replace("/");
        }
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.checkLogged();
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.loaded) {
        if (this.state.confirm) {
          return (
            <AuthComponent
              history={this.props.history}
              confirm={this.state.confirm}
            />
          );
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  };

  return AuthWrapped;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are using the authentication system the wrong way
In React everything should exist in a hierarchical manner.

In your case, you have an Auth state that would change and when the loggedIn state changes, everything should re-render. the correct way to do this is using the Context API to handle the logged in state so when the state changes, the whole screen would re-render

---

here is the solution to your problem:

*AuthContext.js*

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export class AuthProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
  };

  login = (username, password) => {
    someLoginRequestToServer(username, password).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: response.isLoggedIn,
      });
    });
  };

  logout = () => {
    someLogoutRequestToServer().then(() => {
      this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          loggedIn: this.state.isLoggedIn,
          login: this.login,
          logout: this.logout,
        }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer;
```

*SomeCustomAuthComponent*

```
class CustomAuthComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AuthConsumer>
        {({ loggedIn, login, logout }) => (
          <div>
            <p>You Are {loggedIn ? 'Logged in' : 'Logged out'}</p>
            <button onClick={loggedIn ? () => logout() : () => login('abcd', '12345')} />
          </div>
        )}
      </AuthConsumer>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Or you can use the redux for state management and react-redux as it uses the react Context API under the hood.

hope this helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem lays here

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.checkLogged();
}
```

you're checking if the user is logged only when the component is mounted (after the instantiation). you should be checking it every time the page updates, you have to identify a way to handle this mechanism for example by using the `componentDidUpdate` hook.

```
export default function withAuth(AuthComponent) {
  const Auth = new AuthHelper();

  class AuthWrapped extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        confirm: null,
        loaded: false
      };
    }

    checkIsNotLogged = () => {
      const parent = this.props.parent;
      const obj = this.props.routes
        .filter(v => v.id === parent);
      this.props.history.replace(obj[0].path);
    }

    checkLogged = () => {
      if (!Auth.loggedIn()) {
        this.checkIsNotLogged();

      } else {
        try {
          const confirm = Auth.getConfirm();
          this.setState({
            confirm: confirm,
            loaded: true
          });
        } catch (err) {
          Auth.logout();
          this.props.history.replace("/");
        }
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.checkLogged();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      // do not call here the checkLogged method otherwise you could trigger an infinite loop
      this.checkIsNotLogged();
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.loaded) {
        if (this.state.confirm) {
          return (
            <AuthComponent
              history={this.props.history}
              confirm={this.state.confirm}
            />
          );
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  };

  return AuthWrapped;
}
```